# How do you specify the user that created a CaseComment in a unit test?

Tags: unit-test

```
@isTest static void newComment()
{
    Case theCase = new Case();

    CaseComment caseComment = new CaseComment(ParentId = theCase.Id,
                                             CreatorName = 'User2');
}
```

Trying to save this gives the error:

```
Invalid field CreatorName for SObject CaseComment
```

This confuses me because [the documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_casecomment.htm) shows that `CreatorName` *is* a field on `CaseComment`.

How do I make the `CreatorName` on `caseComment` be what I want on a unit test?

Answer (score 4):

CreatorName is associated with the CreatedById, which is a system field. It is only available in version 26.0 of the API or later and you will need Chatter Answers enabled in order to read this field in apex. In order to create a record as a particular user, you need to use System.runAs(User) in your unit test when creating the CaseComment record.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_testing_tools_runas.htm

EDIT: Note that for portal users, only their first name will show up in this field. Also, this question was mostly answered here in this previous post: [Unable to select CaseComment CreatorName field](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1687/unable-to-select-casecomment-creatorname-field)